# What could cause temperature to be high other than thermal paste and cpu fan not working?

Tags: laptop, cpu, fan, cooling, temperature

I have a Dell Inspiron 17 7737, the temperature at Idle reaches 68 degrees and cpu fan speed 3798 rpm. Now I have already redo the thermal paste and I checked the cpu fan it is working fine. What could be causing the device to overheat?

Comment: It does not sound like your CPU is actually overheating.

Comment: What tool or app are you using to measure the temp? Which OS is used?

Comment: @K7AAY I am using core temp which is found here: https://www.alcpu.com/CoreTemp/

Comment: @K7AAY Also I checked the temp using dell diagnostics from bios and it shows temp at Idle between 58-68.

Comment: Assuming that's 68 degrees Celsius, that's just fine for a powered on CPU (68 degrees Fahrenheit would be extremely cold, unless you're running it outside in the arctic, maybe). Modern CPUs are generally designed to operate just fine up into the high 90s or even a bit over 100 degrees Celsius (~200 degrees F). If it's idling up there, or if you're noticing actual performance issues or a flickering screen, you might have overheating problems, But idling at 68 C or even spending brief periods in the 90s during intensive use should not be terribly concerning.

Comment: @8bittree but when I first time I bought the laptop that was not the normal temperature at Idle.

Comment: @K7AAY Intel Core i7-4500U

Answer (score 0):

Dell's [Inspiron 17 7737 specifications](https://downloads.dell.com/manuals/all-products/esuprt_laptop/esuprt_inspiron_laptop/inspiron-17-7737_reference%20guide_en-us.pdf) show you could have a CPU from three different families of Intel Core Fourth Generation: an i3 , i5, or i7. You cjhecked, and found you have the i7-4500U.

Intel's [specifications](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/75460/intel-core-i7-4500u-processor-4m-cache-up-to-3-00-ghz.html) show the T-Junction, the maximum temperature allowed at the processor die, is 100 degrees Centigrade.

[image: From ark.intel.com]

Therefore, this is not a severe problem.

What could cause it?

A) Dust, dirt, and hair could accumulate within and block the airflow needed to cool the CPU. Solution: Open it and clean it.

B) The CPU fan in this six-and-a-half year old machine may be deteriorating. Solution: Replace the fan.

C) Software installed since installation may have altered the fan configuration. Test: Create a LiveUSB and boot from that instead of your internal drive's OS. Does the fan still run at appx 3800 RPM? If so, then see A) and B).